# Adding a role (autorole) on join from a json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am fairly new to JS, and to learn I decided to make a bot for Discord, I have learned a lot and am continuing to learn. I had the idea for an "autorole". I know the conventional way of doing it.

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', 'Member');
  member.addRole(role);
});
```

However, I want it to get the role from a .json file. The rest of the code is fine, I can write to the json with `>autorole Role`. I am just unsure on how to incorporate the json into the `member.addRole(role)`.

My json looks like this:

```
{
  "505107608391254026": {
    "role": "Staff"
  }
}
```

What I tried, and thought would work is the following. Please remember I am very new before someone decides to slate me for trying to learn and failing.

First I tried this:

```
let auto = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./Storage/autorole.json", "utf8"));
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  var role = member.guild.roles.find('name', auto.role);
  member.addRole(role);
});
```

After that failed, I tried this.

```
let auto = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./Storage/autorole.json", "utf8"));
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  var role = auto.role;
  member.addRole(role);
});
```

Comment: What does that ID (`505107608391254026`) in the JSON stand for? Is it the ID of the guild?

Comment: The ID is the guild ID. Defined via my autorole command
  `autorole[message.guild.id] = {
    role: args[0]
  };`
So if someone runs `prefix autorole Staff`
It will add the guild ID, and then role = Staff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the same method in my discord bot. From what I can tell by your code, you have roles for each user listed under their discord ids in your json file.

EDIT: I didn't realize that was the guild ID. I have changed the below code to accommodate that.

You will want to start out by defining your file as a usable variable if you haven't already:

```
var jsonPath = 'path to json here';
var jsonRead = fs.readFileSync(jsonPath);
var jsonFile = JSON.parse(jsonRead);
```

Next, define the guild's id in the json file:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    var guildId = member.guild.id;
    let autoRole = jsonFile[guildId]
})
```

Since that is done, we can now define the role we want to give as `autoRole.role`

My complete code would be:

```
var jsonPath = 'path to json here';
var jsonRead = fs.readFileSync(jsonPath);
var jsonFile = JSON.parse(jsonRead);

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    var guildId = member.guild.id;
    let autoRole = jsonFile[guildId]
    let myRole = member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === autoRole.role);
    member.addRole(myRole)
})
```

EDIT:
To help with what you asked in your comment, you could add `if (!jsonFile[guildId])` with an else statement. In other words, if your object doesn't exist, do this.

Code:

```
var jsonPath = 'path to json here';
var jsonRead = fs.readFileSync(jsonPath);
var jsonFile = JSON.parse(jsonRead);

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    var guildId = member.guild.id;
    if (!jsonFile[guildId]) {
        console.log('Role could not be found')
    } else {
        let autoRole = jsonFile[guildId]
        let myRole = member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === autoRole.role);
        member.addRole(myRole)
    }
})
```

Comment: Hey I don't suppose you could help again?
Can you make the `addRole` return if the json file is empty? I added a toggle, so if autorole is turned off, the json will have no content, but currently it will throw an error as it tries to add a role from a file that does not exist. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey! I added what you asked for as an edit to my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it says `guildId is not defined` referring to `if (!jsonFile[guildId]) {`

Comment: Oops. `guildId` Needs to be defined *before* the if statement.

Comment: Could you add it to your EDIT please? Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yup! My answer above has been adjusted accordingly.