# I need a AutoRole command when somebody joins my server

Tags: discord.js

I need a AutoRole command discord.js when somebody join my discord server he gets the Discord Member role.

Ive tryied some code but it doesnt work.

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require('../config.json');

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    let target = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ');
    let logs = message.guild.channels.find('name', config.logsChannel);

    if (!message.member.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) return message.reply('you do not have permissions to use this command!s');

    if (!target) return message.reply('please specify a member to ban!');
    if (!reason) return message.reply('please specify a reason for this ban!');
    if (!logs) return message.reply(`please create a channel called ${config.logsChannel} to log the bans!`);

    let embed = new discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setThumbnail(target.user.avatarURL)
        .addField('Banned Member', `${target.user.username} with an ID: ${target.user.id}`)
        .addField('Banned By', `${message.author.username} with an ID: ${message.author.id}`)
        .addField('Banned Time', message.createdAt)
        .addField('Banned At', message.channel)
        .addField('Banned Reason', reason)
        .setFooter('Banned user information', target.user.displayAvatarURL);

    message.channel.send(`${target.user.username} was banned by ${message.author} for ${reason}`);
    target.ban(reason);
    logs.send(embed);

};

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'ban'
};
```

When they join they get the Discord Member role.

Comment: you should paste the code instead of a screenshot of it

Comment: Could you please paste the code here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a role (autorole) on join from a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123986/adding-a-role-autorole-on-join-from-a-json-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `guildMemberAdd` event to do actions on new users.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    member.addRole('ROLE ID HERE')
});
```